# Need help/explanation to JOINED query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm kinda lost on what kind of SQL query I should do to achieve what I want.

Let's say I have three tables :

```
select * FROM trip;

| trip_id | title  | description 
----------------------------------
| 1       | title1 | desc1       | 
| 2       | title2 | desc2       |
| 3       | title3 | desc3       |
| 4       | title4 | desc4       |
| 5       | title5 | desc5       |
| 6       | title6 | desc6       |

select * FROM weekly_report;

| report_id | trip_id| incident_id
----------------------------------
| 1         | 1      | (null)      | 
| 2         | 1      | (null)      |
| 3         | 1      | 1           |
| 4         | 2      | 2           |
| 5         | 3      | 3           |
| 6         | 3      | (null)      |


select * FROM incident;

| incident_id | error_code | 
----------------------------------
| 1           | 22223      | 
| 2           | 25456      | 
| 3           | 25456      |
```

So for a little operationnal knowledge :

- The trip table contains 1 record PER trip done by the customer.
- The weekly_report contains A report per Week of the trip. (1 trip of 2 weeks will have 2 records, 1 trip or 5 weeks will have 5.. ).
- The incident table contains 1 record per incident. (If an incident happened during a week : we create a record in the incident table, else we do nothing)

I'd like to find in a single query (or if it has to be, with subqueries) the number of trips where during at least a week there has been an incident declared for the error_code "25456".

Expected result from the sample data : 2 ( because for trip 2 and three there exist an incident with the error code 25456 ).

I can explain more if needed, is there anybody out there willing to help me ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take count of *distinct* trips for related incidents

```
select count(distinct w.trip_id)
from weekly_report w
inner join incident i
on w.incident_id = i.incident_id
where i.error_code = 25456;
```

Comment: Seems like this is doing it ! I'm gonna study the inner join to understand it ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT w.trip_id
FROM incident i
INNER JOIN weekly_report w ON i.incident_id=w.incident_id
WHERE error_code='25456'
```

and if you want the count,then

```
SELECT COUNT(w.trip_id)
FROM incident i
INNER JOIN weekly_report w ON i.incident_id=w.incident_id
WHERE error_code='25456'
```

Comment: if there was one more incident for trip 2, your answer will produce 3 instead of 2

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Do you think for the same trip there will be 2 incidents?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh trip id might repeat in weekly_report table, but incident_id is kept as unique.It looks like that for me, What you say?